# Bi-directional messaging with spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, distributed-transactions

I'm relatively new to spring integration but I have been tasked with implementing a tcp gateway that needs to:

- Listen for messages on a socket
- Receive a message
- Process the message and write some data to a queue
- Return a response message to the original socket.

In my experience with spring integration, the message flow has not been bi-directional. I've only configured routers to listen, handle messages, and output to queue/topic. In this case, though, I need to accept messages and return a response while also forwarding on some message to a queue. Suggestions?

This is my integration xml so far.

```
<int:chain input-channel="tcpChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="tcpHandler" method="handleInput" />
</int:chain>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway 
             id="tcpGateway"
             connection-factory="tcpServer" 
             request-channel="tcpChannel" />
```

How can I have the output of handleInput be forwarded to a queue but also have some response sent back from the gateway?

Edit: After the conversation below with Gary, this seems to be the pattern we want to follow:

```
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="tcpGateway"
                            connection-factory="tcpServer"
                            request-channel="tcpChannel"
                            reply-channel="tcpReplyChannel"/>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="tcpChannel" />

<int:chain input-channel="tcpChannel">
    <!-- int:json-to-object-transformer type="com.heb.revo.events.RxPosCredit" /-->
    <int:service-activator ref="tcpHandler" method="handleInputToQueue" />
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter destination-name="${queue.response}" />
</int:chain>

<int:service-activator id="tcpResponseHandler"
                       ref="tcpHandler" method="replyToSocket"
                       input-channel="tcpChannel"
                       output-channel="tcpReplyChannel" />

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="tcpReplyChannel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your chain has no `output-channel` the framework will route the return value of the `handleInput` method back to the gateway automatically.

If you want to capture the result and send it somewhere else (as well as a reply), create a `<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="foo"/>`, set the `output-channel` of the chain to `foo`, set the `reply-channel` on the gateway to `foo`, and subscribe another endpoint to `foo` (as an `input-channel`.

Comment: So in this instance the message that is received by the reply channel and the other endpoint will be the same? In my use case the "other endpoint to foo" needs to send a message to a queue that is different than the response to the gateway.

Comment: Yes, it will be the same. You need to state your question more clearly; you want the reply "sent to a queue and have some response". What kind of queue? What would the response contain if it's not the same reply? If the service activator has and output-channel, the reply will go there; eventually, if you want some reply to go to the gateway, you need an implicit reply (no output-channel on the ultimate consumer) or you need to explicitly send the reply to the gateway's reply-channel.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: the socket that sends the initial message to the gateway is expecting a byte array response. The queue (Tibco EMS) is expecting a java object serialized to json. Two completely different responses going to two destinations but originating from a single gateway and living in a single XATransaction.

Comment: You are still not being clear; I can't anticipate what you are trying to do. The general pattern, though would be gateway->service-activator tp create the polog->pubsubchannel. And pubsubchannel has 2 subscribers a JMS outbound adapter and another service activator that returns the byte[] to the inbound gateway. I don't know why you are talking about XA; TCP is not transactional. Please update your question with a detailed flow of what you are trying to do. Comments are not the right vehicle for this discussion.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. The pattern is what I was trying to identify. As for TCP not being transactional, I was not aware until now. Thanks for your help Gary, I know you're a busy guy as I see you all over the place! I'll update the question with details and the results of this conversation.

Comment: s/tp create the polog/to create the pojo/. Must've been a cosmic ray :)